# Set background-position with 9 rectangles on picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: example: two different images "splitted" into 9 equal pieces]

Hello community,

First of all, excuse my bad Paint skills ;)

The idea is to choose one of those 9 equal rectangles for a background-position in CSS.
The uploader of the image should have the opportunity to set the background-position to where the motive is.

For example: in the left image, there would be a butterfly in the top right corner of the image. So he/she would click on the top right rectangle to "mark" the "anchor" for the background-position of this picture. This is neccesary due to very big images for fullscreen-backgrounds. If the user looks at the webseite on a mobile phone, the butterfly should always be there. Thats why I started to create this rectangles.

My question is: How can I do this?

Some ideas:

- create one DIV container and put the image as a background
- create 9 smaller divs, each 33,3% wide and 33,3% high
- give each div a property by which jQuery can access the value (e.g. "top-left" or "center-center") and store the value in a database
- the change (jQuery onClick) should be set immediately after the click on the image. This means, the uploader should have a little preview.

There's one website which dowes almost the thing i want to have, but only with 3 different "rectangles" (top, center, bottom): http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/background/

I don't want you to give me a full sample code, I just would like to know how "clean" this solution would be or any hints.

Thanks a lot.

Chris

EDIT: For better explanation here a real example:

[image: example]

As you can see, the motive is in the top right corner of the image. When I click on the top right rectangle, the background-position of this image should be set to (in CSS):

```
background-position: top right;
```

This action helps to set the background position for mobile devices or tablets, because the image is way bigger than the display of those devices. [Please check the URL above](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/background/) and check the small image on the right side (you may have to scroll down a bit.) Hover the image with your mouse and click on one of the 3 rectangles.

Comment: I only set those 9 divs in manually and gave them properties (id="top-right") to access them with jQuery. But this was the point when I started to think about the whole thing again (too much code, not clean, etc).

Comment: Don't you simply mean cropping the image?

Comment: No, because if I crop the image, then the width and height of the image would not be useable for big screens. I just want to set a background-position for this image, as shown in the URL above.